# How to check if your program is out of range in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, boolean, cs50

I have a program which applies filters to the images. I have a 2D array to spot the pixels. The type of these values are `BYTE` which holds a value between 0-255. The struct of the type;

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

and the 2D array from this struct;

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed
image[i][j].rgbtGreen
image[i][j].rgbtBlue
```

I loop through all the pixels in this 2D array and change the RGB values with the average values of the surrounding pixels. If it's a middle pixel I get average of 9 pixels. But in case it's a corner or edge, it could be average of 4 or 6 pixels. At some point I have to check if the location I'm pointing in this array is true. Is there any way to check this?

For example if program calculates this location in this array `image[56][93].rgbtRed` and it's out of the range of this array, how can I check this?

This is a problem set I'm working in CS50 so I'm not looking for a direct code answer but mostly the method I should use.

I'm beginner so if you explain where I'm exacty wrong, would be much appreciated. Tia

Comment: Since you created the array you should know its bounds. You have to have the sizes stored somewhere where you can compare before accessing elements

Comment: On top of what @UnholySheep said, I presume you are able to read the size of `image`, and place it in the loop as a boundary.

Comment: We would also like to see what you have tried. Please add a piece of code block which works.

Comment: You check if the pixel you want to include is on the image with a simple comparison of its coordinates with the image dimensions. If it isn't you ignore it, if it is you add it to the neighbour sum and increment the pixel count by 1. So at a corner there will be a count of 4 pixels summed, you divide the sum by the count. At the next pixel to be blurred, you start be zeroing the pixel count and the neighbour sum.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I've implemented this as an `if` condition, worked perfectly.